# VB.NET - how to add a title on top of printed page in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, printdocument

I have a windows application on VB.net 2010 and a datagridview inside,

all works fine and the printing also, but I would like to add a Title on the printed page! from textbox that I have, is it possible?

Please replay as soon as you can, and this is my PrintDocument code attached!

```
With DataGridView1
        Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
        Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
        Do While mRow < .RowCount
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
            Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
            Dim h As Single = 0
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                If (newpage) Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                Else
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                End If
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            Next
            newpage = False
            y += h
            mRow += 1
            If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                mRow -= 1
                newpage = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
        mRow = 0
    End With
```

And also, can I adjust the space from the top of the page?
Thanx in advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

This code might works , try it . But it is a little bit different from your code.

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click

With Printer
Printer.Title = "Your Title" 'You can change this by TextBox1.text
Printer.SubTitle = "Your Subtitle" 'You can change this by TextBox2.text
Printer.SubTitleFormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit Or _
StringFormatFlags.NoClip
Printer.PageNumbers = True
Printer.PageNumberInHeader = False
Printer.PorportionalColumns = True
Printer.HeaderCellAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
Printer.Footer = "Your Footer"
Printer.FooterSpacing = 15
Printer.PrintDataGridView(Me.DataGridView1)
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Printer is not declared, says my vb.net =(

Comment: Try the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the above code doesn't work , you can try this one.

```
Private PrintGrid As DataGridViewPrint
Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
Dim fpr As New frmPrint()
With fpr
.Title = DataGridView1.CaptionText
.ShowDialog()
If .Result > 0 Then
PrintGrid = New DataGridViewPrint(PrintDocument1, DataGridView1, .bBlackWhite)
PrintGrid.PrintTitle = .bTitle
PrintGrid.Title = .Title
Select Case .Result
Case 1 ' Print
' The Print method prints the DataGridView without using a print dialog.
' Use a PrintDialog when you want to offer the user the ability to choose print settings.
If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then PrintDocument1.Print()
Case 2 ' Page Setup
PageSetupDialog1.ShowDialog()
Case 3 ' Preview
PrintPreviewDialog1.Icon = fpr.Icon
PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Select
End If
End With
End Sub

' Specify the output to print by handling the PrintPage event 
' and by using the Graphics included in the PrintPageEventArgs.
Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
' Print method of DataGridViewPrint class starts the custom DataGridView's printing process.
e.HasMorePages = PrintGrid.Print(e.Graphics)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution useful!

Try to add this into Printducoment method:

```
' Create string to draw.
Dim drawString As [String] = "Sample Text"

' Create font and brush.
Dim drawFont As New Font("Arial", 16)
Dim drawBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)

' Create rectangle for drawing.
Dim x As Single = 150.0F
Dim y As Single = 150.0F
Dim width As Single = 200.0F
Dim height As Single = 50.0F
Dim drawRect As New RectangleF(x, y, width, height)

' Draw rectangle to screen.
Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black)
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, x, y, width, height)

' Set format of string.
Dim drawFormat As New StringFormat
drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

' Draw string to screen.
e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, _
drawRect, drawFormat)
```

And it worked just fine as drawing a text on top of my Datagrideview page ^^

Thanks 'mark ashraf' for your answers <3